# Change text color on div hover

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

How can I change the text color inside a div on hover?
The text color doesn't seem to change, but everything else does

Here's a look at what am talking about

```html
<div className="hover:bg-blue-100 hover:border-blue-500 hover:text-blue-600">
    <p>Change textcolor inside here....</p>
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div className="hover:bg-blue-100 hover:border-blue-500 hover:text-blue-600">
    <p>Change textcolor inside here....</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If this is not react, then it should be `class` instead of `className`. Check if you have other css rules about `p` that set the color.

Comment: Also, what does this have to to with JS? Tailwind is a CSS framework that works with HTML `class` attributes.

Comment: I just added the Javascript tag to get the attention of Javascript community on here....

Comment: I added a snippet with tailwind and react but it is not really "react ready" perhaps with that markup  Perhaps use this guide https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/125981

Answer (score 1):

As Gabriele mentioned, use the `class` attribute if this is standard HTML and not JSX.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="hover:bg-blue-100 hover:border-blue-500 hover:text-blue-600">
  <p>Change textcolor inside here....</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the aspect of an element with hover, you have to put this into the css:

```
.myelementclass:hover {
 color:red;
 }
```

where red could be any other color and .myelemntclass is just the class name of your element.